# Google signin in react-native-webview seems not working. Any solution guys?

Tags: android, ios, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview in my react-native app. I have applied many solutions to this but none of them working. I have used npm user-agent package too. Can't find any way guys. please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? If Firebase, have you updated the SHA1 keys or have you enabled the Authentication in Firebase? Where is your code?

Comment: No. I haven't tried that but I would definately give it a try. thank you @LalitFauzdar

Comment: If you've not updated the SHA1 keys, Google Auth won't work without it.